# Exit macro for navigation form. Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

For some reason when I try to create the exit macro it doesn't give me the option to choose anything after clicking "run macro".

I dragged the button button into the header, from the command button wizard >>>clicked miscellaneous>>>clicked Run Macro>>>and all I got was a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

If by "blank screen" you actually mean an empty list, that is because the `Miscellaneous | Run Macro` choice implies that you want to run an **existing macro**. All of the other options in the button wizard will generate very specific macros to perform the selected operation (even though they don't say "macro").  For instance, if you want to "exit" the form, you could choose `Form Operations | Close Form` and it will generate an embedded macro for the button to do just what you selected.